# matplotlib.pyplot format string kwarg?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm reading the `matplotlib` [docs](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html). I'm struggling to find the keyword argument for the 'format string'. Or it is a positional arg only?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a specific `pyplot` argument (sort of a remnant of the older `pylab`). In `'ro'`, `r` means red, and 'o' means a round marker.

The arguments can be set like this instead:

```
color='r'
marker='.'
linestyle='-'  # if you need the dots connected by a line
```

Scroll down to see the [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`: Format Strings](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) section. `'[marker][line][color]'`

```py
plt.plot(range(1, 5), range(1, 17, 4), 'o-r')

# is equivalent to
plt.plot(range(1, 5), range(1, 17, 4), marker='o', linestyle='-', color='red')
```

Comment: So if you want to use keyword arguments. The format string needs to be pulled apart and supplied as individual components?

Comment: Ok, ta. That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [proof](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) from the matplotlib documentation that there is no such named argument - see "This argument cannot be passed as keyword.".